# Fit view and showing user location on Google map along with all other markers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Fit view and showing user location on Google map along with all other markers

Hello guys.
I have prepared for you jsfiddle to ilustrate what are the problems. First of all google map loads specific markers positions from database. This is working well. In the fiddle the user is offered by the browser either to share his position or not. Here comes my question 1:
1. How to make browser to ask for user position only if user click on button Show my position. How to implement it in the code? If not clicked Show my position google map to show the other markers..
2. How to fit on screen and make visible all markers WHEN user has clicked Show my position

```
<button>Show my position</button>
<div id="googlemap"></div>
```

Here is [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4deLywsd/13/)

For some reason jsfiddle doesnt work on IE !
Thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an ID to your button, for example:

```
<button id="showPosition">Show my position</button>
```

Use the `fitBounds()` method to include the user location on the map.

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);

        marker = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            zoom: 5,
            content: 'You are here !',

        });
        bounds.extend(marker.position);

        map.fitBounds(bounds); // fit the map with the extended bounds

    }, function () {
        handleNoGeolocation(true);
    });
} else {
    // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
    handleNoGeolocation(false);
}
```

And wrap your code in a click event listener:

**Standard way**

```
document.getElementById("showPosition").addEventListener('click', function () {

    // code goes here
});
```

**Google maps way**

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('showPosition'), 'click', function () {

    // code goes here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

1. To get browser to ask for user permission only when 'Show my position' button is clicked, add a `onclick` to the button and upn the click, check for `navigator.geolocation` condition.

Like this :

```
<button id="showMe">Show my position</button>
```

Handling user permission :

```
document.getElementById("showMe").addEventListener('click', function () {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        // If user grants permission
    } 
});
```

Now, browser will ask for permission only when the button is clicked.

2. To fit the new marker in map area, use `bounds` to include new marker and then fit the map like this :

   ```
   bounds.extend(pos);
   map.fitBounds(bounds);
   ```

Hence, your new code will look like this :

```
document.getElementById("showMe").addEventListener('click', function () {
    if(navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);

        marker = new google.maps.InfoWindow ({
            map: map,
            position: pos,
            zoom:5,
            content: 'You are here !'
        });

    bounds.extend(pos);      // adding new marker to bounds.
    map.fitBounds(bounds);   // fit the map to cover bounds.

    }, function() {
           handleNoGeolocation(true);
       });
    } else {
        handleNoGeolocation(false);
    }
});
```

Here is updated **[jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/4deLywsd/18/)**